# Why this semaphores stuck

Tags: c, semaphore

I make program which exec 2 times this code. 2 process enter to semaphore and stuck(HERE comment). Why it happen and how to fix it?

```
sem_t *sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_RDWR);
if (sem == SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("sem_open(3) failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int j = atoi(argv[1]);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)  {
  printf("%i\n",getpid() );
   //HERE!!!!!
   if (sem_wait(sem) < 0) {
    perror("sem_wait(3) failed on child");}

    printf("PID %ld acquired semaphore\n", (long) getpid());

    if (sem_post(sem) < 0) {
      perror("sem_post(3) error on child");}
         printf("wysz\n");

    sleep(1);
}

semcl(sem);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the semaphore using this

```
sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_RDWR,0777, 1);
```

to set the starting value of the semaphore to 1.

Comment: Work as mad! Thanks!